# Qt - no such signal error

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to trigger a signal when a double click happens in one of the draggable widgets on the [fridge magnets example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/draganddrop-fridgemagnets.html). Here's the changes I made to the example source:

DragLabel:

```
class DragLabel : public QLabel
{
public:
    DragLabel(const QString &text, QWidget *parent);
    QString labelText() const;

public slots:
    void testSlot(){qDebug()<<"testSlot";}    //<-- implemented this slot

protected:
    void mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *ev){emit testSignal();}    //<-- overriden this method

private:
    QString m_labelText;

signals:
    void testSignal();    //<-- added this signal

};
```

The only thing I changed in the implementation file is adding `connect(this,SIGNAL(testSignal()),this,SLOT(testSlot()));` to DragLabel's constructor.

Trying to compile the project resulted in '*undefined reference to `DragLabel::testSignal()*' and '*collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*' errors.

When I comment out the call to the signal, it compiles and runs, but gives off '*Object::connect: No such signal QLabel::testSignal() in draglabel.cpp*' warning in the application output. Apparently testSignal() isn't being recognized as a signal.

I've tried to add the Q_OBJECT macro to DragLabel but it results in 4 '*undefined reference to `vtable for DragLabel'*' warnings and a '*collect2: ld returned 1 exit status*' error.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your sample code is missing the Q_OBJECT macro call, which might be the cause of your problems.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention that, I did try to add Q_OBJECT before. I'll add that to the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put the Q_OBJECT macro at the top, (must be first thing in the class and no ";" )

Make sure you do a full rebuild, the VS-add-in especially doesn't always notice that a file has become qt-aware without a rebuild.

More good advice [20 ways to debug Qt signals and slots](http://samdutton.wordpress.com/2008/10/03/debugging-signals-and-slots-in-qt/)

Comment: It WAS the macro in the end. I had to reboot my PC for it to work though, cleaning and rebuilding the project didn't work out. Before rebooting Qt Creator kept giving the 'ld returned 1 exit status' error and the vtable warnings. Really weird.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Your link saved my life. In my case for the same error, it was a parameter mismatch in signal and slot functions.

Comment: @Anisha Kaul - signal/slots are run time so the compiler doesn't notice errors. I had one today where I had the case of a single letter wrong in the middle of one signal name!

Comment: @MartinBeckett Compiler doesn't even catch syntax error! That's terrifying. :(

Comment: @Anisha - well it's useful in you can send a signal to a runtime component that might not be loaded. So you can broadcast signals to slots that don't exist - but it's hard to catch. Although you can write a macro to trap it at runtime

Answer (score 0):

> It WAS the macro in the end. I had to reboot my PC for it to work though, cleaning and rebuilding the project didn't work out. Before rebooting Qt Creator kept giving the 'ld returned 1 exit status' error and the vtable warnings. Really weird. – David McDavidson

It's not weird, it's stupid.
I got the same error, but I make it after rearrange the .h files. Say:

1 classA.h include calssB.h ;

2 classB.h declared two class, classB and classC, (classB.h declared signals & slot)

I do three things,

1. seperate classC to another .h file
2. eliminate all forward class declaration about classB
3. classB.h included by classA.cpp, other than by classA.h

after that, QT compiled it. I'll test if it is working.