# Enum signal parameter

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to use Qt's signals-and-slots mechanism with custom enumeration types.

I have read all the following, and none of it helped:

- http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtbinding.html#using-enumerations-of-a-custom-type
- [Qt - no such signal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610151/qt-no-such-signal-error)
- [Qt signal with an enum as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030601/qt-signal-with-an-enum-as-a-parameter)

DetectorEngineThread.h:

```
class DetectorEngineThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_ENUMS(ErrorCode)
    Q_ENUMS(Status)

public:
    enum ErrorCode
    {
        ...
    };

    enum Status
    {
        ...
    };
...

signals:
    void statusChanged(Status newStatus);
    void processingError(ErrorCode code);
};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode)
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(DetectorEngineThread::Status)
```

MainWindow.h:

```
...
#include "DetectorEngineThread.h"
...

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    ...

private:
    DetectorEngineThread* m_detEng;
    ...

private slots:
    void on_detEng_statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status newStatus);
    void on_detEng_processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode errorCode);
    ...
};
```

MainWindow.cpp:

```
...
#include "MainWindow.h"
...

MainWindow::MainWindow(...) : ...
{
    ...
    qRegisterMetaType<DetectorEngineThread::Status>("DetectorEngineThread::Status");
    qRegisterMetaType<DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode>("DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode");
    ...

    m_detEng = new DetectorEngineThread(...);

    connect(m_detEng, SIGNAL(statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status)),
            this, SLOT(on_detEng_statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status)), Qt::QueuedConnection);

    connect(m_detEng, SIGNAL(processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode)),
            this, SLOT(on_detEng_processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode)), Qt::QueuedConnection);
    ...
}
...

void MainWindow::on_detEng_statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status newStatus)
{
    ...
}

void MainWindow::on_detEng_processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode errorCode)
{
    ...
}
...
```

During runtime, I get the following messages (in the Application Output panel in Qt Creator):

> Object::connect: No such signal
>   DetectorEngineThread::statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status) in ...
>   Object::connect: No such signal
>   DetectorEngineThread::processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode) in ...

And obviously the slots' code never run, despite the fact that matching signals are emitted.

I tried:

- moving the enums into global scope, but the problem remained.
- having the signals and the slots connected automatically via QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName, but that met with the same issue.
- using the local names (e.g. Status instead of DetectorEngineThread::Status) in qRegisterMetaType and Q_DECLARE_METATYPE, and also tried to use these in the SIGNAL and SLOT macros.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enums declared in signals and slots should be fully qualified so:

```
void statusChanged(Status newStatus);
void processingError(ErrorCode code);
```

Should be:

```
void statusChanged(DetectorEngineThread::Status newStatus);
void processingError(DetectorEngineThread::ErrorCode code);
```

Comment: I got the same problem, except that it didn't even show me the runtime error message! Qualifying the enum type in my signal declaration solved the problem.

Comment: This solution works. However, a problem with it is that, quite often, a Qt application works fine without fully-qualified enums as signal argument types, especially if the application does not involve multi-threading. When multi-threading is involved, I often get the following Qt error message using Qt 5.4:    QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'ErrorType'
(Make sure 'ErrorType' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)         So my follow-up question is: Can Qt be enhanced to accept non-fully qualified enum types as signal function arguments? What would be the difficulties?

Comment: @jonathanz Your issue has nothing to do with the OPs question (types have to registered via `qRegisterMetaType()` in order to be added to the event queue in threads).  Ask your question as a new one.

Comment: @cmannett85 Actually I did use qRegisterMetaType() but still occasionally got the above-mentioned Qt error message which is misleading. Your solution has fixed my issue. So I added a comment which may be helpful to other developers. I'm not sure if asking a new question to stackoverflow will help, as this looks more like an enhancement request to the Qt development team.