# Opening a Window with a QPushButton C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to Qt Creator and I'm trying to build a first window with a button that open a new window. I've followed many tutorial that ended up with the same problem:

QObject::connect: No such signal QPushButton::click() in ../Gestion_Travaux/MainWindow.cpp:23

So there is my code:

Main.cpp

```
   #include <QApplication>
   #include "MainWindow.h"


    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        MainWindow frame;
        frame.show();

        return app.exec();
    }
```

MainWindow.h

```
  #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
  #define MAINWINDOW_H
  #include <QApplication>
  #include <QWidget>
  #include <QPushButton>
  #include "NewJobWindow.h"

  class MainWindow : public QWidget // On hérite de QWidget (IMPORTANT)
  {
      public:
      MainWindow(); //Fenetre principale

      public slots:
      void OpenNew();


      private:
      QPushButton *m_NewJob; 
      QPushButton *m_OldJob; 
      NewJobWindow *m_NewJobWindow;
    };


#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include "NewJobWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include <QSlider>

MainWindow::MainWindow() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(500, 500);

    // Construction du bouton nouveau travail
    m_NewJob = new QPushButton("Nouveau Travail", this);
    m_NewJob->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    m_NewJob->setGeometry(30,30,140,30);

    // Construction du bouton nouveau travail
    m_OldJob = new QPushButton("Travail archive", this);
    m_OldJob->setCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor);
    m_OldJob->setGeometry(30,70,140,30);

    connect(m_NewJob, SIGNAL(click()), this, SLOT(openNew()));
}

void MainWindow::OpenNew()
{
    m_NewJobWindow= new NewJobWindow(); // Be sure to destroy you window somewhere
    m_NewJobWindow->show();

}
```

NewJobWindow.h

```
#ifndef NEWJOBWINDOW_H
#define NEWJOBWINDOW_H


#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

class NewJobWindow : public QWidget // On hérite de QWidget (IMPORTANT)
{
    public:
    NewJobWindow(); //Fenetre de nouveau travail

    public slots:


    private:
};


#endif // NEWJOBWINDOW_H
```

NewJobWindow.cpp

```
#include "NewJobWindow.h"

NewJobWindow::NewJobWindow() : QWidget()
{
    setFixedSize(500, 500);

};
```

I am sill looking for my error ... 
Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt - no such signal error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610151/qt-no-such-signal-error)

Comment: Note the signal is [clicked](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) not `click`

Comment: Also add the Q_OBJECT macro

Answer (score 2):

- Replace

  ```
  connect(m_NewJob, SIGNAL(click()), this, SLOT(openNew()));
  ```

  with

  ```
  connect(m_NewJob, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openNew()));
  ```
- Add `Q_OBJECT` macro in the beginning of your both classes.

  ```
  class MainWindow : public QWidget // On hérite de QWidget (IMPORTANT)
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      ...
  ```

  and

  ```
  class NewJobWindow : public QWidget // On hérite de QWidget (IMPORTANT)
  {
      Q_OBJECT
      ...
  ```
- Run `qmake` via *Build -> run qmake*.